# ajax request giving unwanted response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have an html page `index.htm` in which I have a link which get the divs via ajax request to another html `zoom.htm`, and appends it to the body, but when I make changes in `zoom.htm`, the changes are not reflected, its something like the `zoom.htm` is saved somewhere (cached) and it is taking divs from that cached (I don't know its really cached or not) page. Even when I removed zoom.htm from my project, it is still showing its content.

```
$.get('zoom.htm', function(html) {
 $(html).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn(500);
}, 'html');
```

1. How can I get fresh copy of zoom.htm every time I make request.
2. When I replace zoom.htm with zoom.jsp (this is what I want to do but I am testing with html page), its not working properly (all the html is same as that of zoom.htm).

Comment: thank you guys for your help...problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

To prevent getting a cached response you just need to make sure the url is unique every time, by appending a timestamp for instance:

```
'zoom.htm?' + new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: if you empty the browser cache after updating zoom.htm, and then try again does that solve it? If not, it's not a problem with caching in the browser at least, so the problem must be on the server side, or a proxy (unlikely though)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your debugger if the response you are getting is from the cache. In Chrome Developer Tools, usually they are marked "(From Cache)". In Chrome, you can force disable the cache as well. Open developer tools and click the gear at the lower right. Then an overlay will show. Click "Disable Cache". Further requests will not use cached objects.

Also, if you are using some kind of CMS, you might want to disable the server-side cache as well if it has the option to do so

---

On the other hand... Are you editing the correct file? You might be editing a copy of the file and not the one you are trying to retrieve. Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test whether the zoom.htm beeing fetched is a cached version, is to clear your browser cache. For instance, "Edit > Preferences > Advanced: Cached Web Content => Clear Now" in Firefox.

And then, assuming your server is Apache-like, you can prevent the browser from caching your zoom.htm file using the Header directive (i.e. create a .htaccess file in your project directory) like this:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

as illustrated in [askapache](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html). Hope it helps.